# Magento 2 - Add Owl Slider in Related Products using requirejs-config.js

Tags: magento2, requirejs, related-products, slider

**Theme Level**

```
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/requirejs-config.js
```

**Owl Carousel JS/CSS path**

```
Vendor_Theme/web/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.css
Vendor_Theme/web/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.js
```

**requirejs-config**

```
var config = {

    paths: {
        'owlcarousel': "Vendor_Theme/web/owl.carousel/owl.carousel"

    },
    shim: {
        'owlcarousel': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
    }
};
```

**Related Products path - Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/template/product/list/items.phtml**

```
<div class="owlslider products wrapper grid products-grid>
<ol class="products list items product-items">

 <script>
    (function  () {
        require(["jquery","owlcarousel"],function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".owlslider").owlCarousel({
                    navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
                    autoPlay: false, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds 
                    items : 5
                });
            });
        });
    })();
</script>
```

1. Owl carousel JS is not being called using requirejs-config
2. How do I add owl carousel to related products ?

The carousel is being added into custom theme and not module.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below code. Sometime in multi-store in M2 custom js does not load with "owlcarousel", so we need to give full path  "Vendor_Theme/web/owl.carousel/owl.carousel".

```
 <script>
    (function  () {
        require(["jquery","Vendor_Theme/web/owl.carousel/owl.carousel"],function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".owlslider").owlCarousel({
                    navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
                    autoPlay: false, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds 
                    items : 5
                });
            });
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: the path is already given in requirejs-config. Is the path incorrect ? How do I make sure if requirejs is actually loading owl carousel js ?

Comment: You can check your js is load in requirejs-config.js over page source. Even you can check in Network area to find js is loading or not.

Comment: and what if it is not loading ? I do not see it in network or view source

Comment: /app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
         <referenceBlock name="head.components">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="default_page_head_components" after='-' template="Magento_Theme::html/js_components.phtml" />
         </referenceBlock>

Magento_Theme::html/js_components.phtml
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{ "*":{
  "Magento_Theme/js/themeOptions":{},
  "Magento_Theme/js/lazysizes":{}
 }
}
</script>

Comment: Can you post above as your answer ?

Comment: yes I have posted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69901/discussion-between-prakash-patel-and-vikram).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

/app/design/frontend///Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
 <referenceBlock name="head.components">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="default_page_head_components" after='-' template="Magento_Theme::html/js_components.phtml" />
     </referenceBlock>



"Magento_Theme::html/js_components.phtml


<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{   "*":{
        "Magento_Theme/js/themeOptions":{},
        "Magento_Theme/js/lazysizes":{}
    }
}
</script>
```